# How can I use Python classes to promote code re-use?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I have two classes that share a lot of common stuff except one function `f(x)`.

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        // some stuff
    def g(self):
        // some other stuff
    def f(self, x):
        // many lines of computations
        q = ...
        y = ...
        return y

class B(A):
    def f(self, x):
        // same many lines as in A
        q = ...
        y = ...
        // a few extra lines
        z = ... # z needs both y and q
        return z
```

In this case, do I have to define `f(x)` from scratch in class B? Is there some trick to re-use the code in `A.f(x)`?

One way I can think of is to make `q` an instance property `self.q`, then do the following

```
def f(self.x):
    y = A.f(self, x)
    // a few extra lines
    z = ... # using y and self.q
    return z
```

Or maybe let `A.f(x)` return both `q` and `y`, then call `A.f(self, x)` in B's definition of `f(x)`.

Are these approaches the standard way to do it? Is there something nicer?

Comment: `self.q` would be an instance property.

Comment: Seems like a valid approach to me. Although does it matter if `B` does not inherit the `g` function?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to organize your code around classes. If that's the case, then I would strongly recommend using `super` to reference the super class:

```
class MyA(object):
    def f(self, x):
        print 'MyA'
        return x


class MyB(MyA):
    def f(self, x):
        print 'MyB'
        print super(MyB, self).f(x)
```

This approach allows you to stick with classes and is an idiomatic way of referencing inherited classes.

If you don't need to organize your code this way or otherwise have reasons to break things out into functions that are usable by other parts of your code which don't care about these classes, then you can move your `f` logic into a function.

Here's an example:

```
def f(x):
  return x


class MyA(object):
    def f(self, x):
        return f(x)


class MyB(MyA):
    def f(self, x):
        y = f(x)
        ...
        return y
```